# Why don't I see the UV map?

Tags: uv-image-editor, versions

I had done my material work on an older version of Blender (2.7).

Now I updated my Blender version, my older mesh had several materials, but now I can only see one.

Why I only see one material? When I select one image of the older, its unwrap right so all is there where it should be, when there was this picture on this place, but when I go to the *UV Image Editor* I can't see the unwrapped mesh.

[image]

Comment: did you open 2.7 .blend file in 2.8+?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The window on the left is the *Image Editor* you need to use the new *UV Editor* to see the unwrap.

Comment: no I think I am on the UV editing. You can see that over the image. UV editing is active. I see know, when i click on the plus and made a new "tab" and chose uv editing.001 i can see the unwrap. But why?

Comment: @Motcho is right, check the editor icon - it's the image editor :).